# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Routes and Passing Parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass parameters to the route but I am having a hard time. I want that when I type "Articles/230" in the URL it should invoke the Detail action as shown below:

```
 public ActionResult Detail(int id)
       {
           return View();
       }
```

I have the following in my Global.asax file:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Articles", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults


            );

            routes.MapRoute(
               "ArticleDetails", // Route name
               "Articles/{id}", // URL with parameters
               new { controller = "Articles", action="Detail", id = 0 } // Parameter defaults

           );

        }
```

And here is the view:

```
@foreach(var article in Model) 
{
    <div class="article_title">
   @Html.ActionLink(@article.Title, "Detail", "Articles", new { id = @article.Id})
    </div>
    <div>
    @article.Abstract
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of routes is important because they are evaluated in the same order they are defined. So oimply invert the order:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "ArticleDetails",
        "Articles/{id}",
        new { controller = "Articles", action = "Detail", id = 0 }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Articles", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Now when you request `Articles/123` it will invoke the `Detail` action on the `Articles` controller and pass `123` as the `id` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Darin! That did work but why is order important and in my original code why did it not match the route even though it was out of order.

Comment: The route engine works on the basis of lazy matching. Because the default route doesn't have anything to match (all values have a default), it'll match before anything else.

Comment: Order is important because there has to be *some* order in which it evaluates route info. :) Your original ordering did not work because Articles/123 attempted to invoke the "123" action of the "Articles" controller, which did not exist. It matches the first (default) route.

Comment: @johndoe, routes are evaluated in the same order as they are defined. So when you request `Articles/123` the first route definition matches: controller = Articles, Action = 123, id = null and because there is not such action on this controller you get an error.